# What's the runtime complexity of a recursive tree algorithm which is quadratic in the number of distinct child subtree sizes?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, big-o, dynamic-programming

I have an algorithm which operates on a rooted tree. It first recursively computes results for each of the root's child subtrees. It then does some work to combine them. The amount of work at the root is K^2 where K is the number of distinct values among the sizes of the subtrees.

What's the best bound on its runtime complexity? I haven't been able to construct a case in which it does more than linear work in the size of the tree.

Comment: By "each subtree", do you actually mean each subtree, or just the subtrees rooted at the children?

Comment: Just the child subtrees of the root. I've updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is governed by the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) of divide and conqour algorithms. For this particular case (me reading between the lines in what you have described) it is mainly determined by how much work it takes on a single node to combine the work compiled for K values in the subtrees. Specifically if it is less than K work, then the cost is dominated by the cost at the lowest level and would be `O(K)` in total, if the work at a given level is `O(K)` then the total work becomes `O(K log(K))`. For work at a level higher than `O(K)`, it is dominated by the work at the higest level. We therefor have that your algorithm as a runtime complexity of `O(K^2)`.

Comment: It takes Ω(K^2) nodes to make children with K distinct sizes, though

Comment: You need to write it in terms of children instead of distinct children. In such a case the work would likely be closer to `O(K^2 log(K))`, though I havent run the specific numbers (just assuming they cancel out nicely), so it would be advisable to go through the master theorem with your actual analysis.

Comment: The Master Theorem applies to divide-and-conquer algorithms where sub-problems have equal size, which is not true here. The sub-problem sizes are dictated by the structure of the tree.